# Antd Table horizontal scroll with not fixed width

Tags: reactjs, antd

I just start working with Ant Design and I encounter a problem with Table. Here is my code

```
<div className="main-table">
  <Table
    rowSelection={{
      type: 'checkbox',
      ...rowSelection,
    }}
    columns={dataColumns}
    dataSource={dataOrder}
    bordered
    pagination={{ pageSize: 50 }}
    scroll={{ x: 'true', y: 240 }}
  />
</div>
```

My current layout has a sidebar on the left, and a table on the right. In `dataSource`, I set width to every columns, have a fixed header and the last column has the attribute `fixed: right`. The div with class 'main-table' has width: 100%. The result is that table displays on the whole page, not scrolling only in table. I suppose that is because there is no fixed width (when I set width to 1000px, it can scroll inside table). I want to keep width to 100%. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you try `scroll={{ x: 'max-content', y: 240 }}`

Comment: I tried. But then it display the whole table on screen and having scroll on whole screen, not inside table

Comment: Can you please create a code sandbox?